# Linux live boot vs install on external hard drive

Tags: linux, multi-boot

I'm trying to understand the differences between a live boot and an install on an external hard drive.

I have a hard drive design to support windows to go. Which I've partitioned to have a live boot sector. And an unformatted sector.

I want to install Linux on to the unpartitioned section external hard drive.  However I'm a bit confused on the differences between live boot and a direct install.

1. If I install Linux onto my external hard drive, am I tied to that hardware. Eg after install can I connect that disk to another computer and boot from that hard drive?
2. What are the differences in performance, is live boot much slower than an install to an external HDD?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Live linux boot is helpful when you have to do recovery tasks. Anything you do will not be persistent and will vanish after you shutdown like you install a package or updates it will not stay. But any other work like you create documents, spreadsheets or presentations then you can mount another file system and store it there. Usually you have few disk space in that because USB, DVD and CDs are very small. It works entirely from RAM. Performance issues aren't that much. Live boot is usually slower than booting installed linux.

There is another kind of live boot with persistence. It creates a persistent file in your boot media and all work is stored in that file. The file has casper-rw file system. It also doesn't touch your hard disk and works like internal SATA connection. But if you have smaller disks, your disk space is low.

Installing linux in hard drive is the full meal deal. You can take full advantage of the partition in hard drive. You can save and work more. The only reason I see to not install it is you don't want to (re-)partition your hard disk.

Comment: Thanks, I'm still confused about my first question.  If you install Linux on an external hard drive. Can I boot from that hard drive if I out it into another computer?

Comment: Yes, you can boot.